# Compare dates within same column MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want the date_end column to iteratively compare the next row and delete it until the date_end is greater than in it. e.g

```
 R|      date_end
 1|       1993-12-20
 2|       1993-11-17
 3|  1993-11-17
 4|   1993-12-30
 5|   1993-12-30
 6|   1994-01-21  
 7|   1993-01-05
```

---

I want to store Row 1, 4, 6 in a new temporary table.
I have used the self join technique unsuccessfully.
There are other column in the table as well.

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    b.datestart AS datestart2,
    b.hourtimestart AS hourtimestart2,
    b.dateend AS dateend2,
    b.hourtimeend AS hourtimeend2,
    b.Amount AS Amount2,
    b.mintime AS mintime2
FROM
    tempdb.combined3 a,
    tempdb.combined4 b;

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tempdb.combined5
WHERE
    (dateend < datestart2)
ORDER BY datestart , datestart2;
```

[image]

UPDATE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6JCMtaMJvrq9D6vZZFu8xt/2

Comment: If 'it' is 1, then I don't understand why '1' would be included in this result

Comment: @strawberry I am not sure what you mean by both of your comments.
I have added a fiddle, though.

Comment: We have differing interpretations of the term 'minimal'!!

Comment: I have provided plenty data so that it is easy to answer and easier to understand for other community members later on. @strawberry

Comment: Other community members like minimal, complete, reproducible examples too.

Comment: Sure, next time I would keep that in mind.
I joined stackoverflow just yesterday.
You could help me by solving the problem.
Cheers :) @strawberry

Comment: Help us to help you by following the advice provided.

Answer (score 1):

I cursor would do that for you. I'm no MySQL expert but I think this would work. It basically converts a select into a loop in which you may interact with the variables.

Please check that code sample:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN

  DECLARE current datetime2;
  DECLARE previous datetime2;

  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT b.dateend AS dateend2
        FROM tempdb.combined4 b;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO current;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;    

    IF current > previous THEN
      /* insert into your table here */
      SET previous = current;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

You may check more about cursors here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: @SaadAmir provide me with a sample data so I may test that on my end. Can you post the create table with some data sample so I may test that? indeed I was not able to test that script since I have no data like that on my end.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**

Try this query

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN A.DateEnd > B.DateEnd THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS checking
 FROM combined4 A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT r-1 AS BR,R,DateEnd FROM combined4) B
ON A.R=BR
HAVING checking=1;
```

Comment: I added R column but it is still not working. The following rows appeared.

1
7
9
11
13
14
18 and so on

Comment: can you [update the fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6JCMtaMJvrq9D6vZZFu8xt/0) with your original table structure and data? you can insert data where `R` from 1 to 20. Copy your own original query into the fiddle as well. Once you've done that, please click "Update" and [copy the fiddle link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61263278/edit) into your question. Thanks

Comment: I have done as you said with 200 rows.
Here is the link. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6JCMtaMJvrq9D6vZZFu8xt/2
@tcadidot0

Comment: @SaadAmir , I think I made a mistake,how did I get the correct value in the first place? Could you please check the updated query in my answer, does it return correctly? Thanks

Comment: It is not updated. Can you please provide fiddle link?
@tcadidot0

Comment: Sorry, here is the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6JCMtaMJvrq9D6vZZFu8xt/3